# How return IEnumerable<T>/IList<T> is null or value using null-coalescing operator

Tags: c#

I want to use the null-coalescing operator with three Statements.

1. If the first list returns null then return the second list
2. If second list returns null then return the third list

   ```
    private IList<a> a => new IList<a>().ToList();
    private IList<a> CalcDate
    {
        get
        {
            return a.Where(p => p.a.LastDate.HasValue && p.a.LastDateHasValue <= DateTime.Today)
        ?? a.Where(p => p.LastUpdateDate.HasValue && p.LastUpdateDate <= DateTime.Today)
        ?? a.Where(p => p.CreateDate.HasValue && p.CreateDate <= DateTime.Today);
        }
    }
   ```

I don't want to use `?:` operator, because I want to keep the code short.
Please help me with ideas for short and readable code and more tips

Comment: Unfortunately that's not easily done as each of the calls to `.Where` will return a collection, even if the collection is empty. In other words, you will get the results from the first Where call even if that is empty, then the result will be empty, even if one of the other two Where calls would produce something. You will need to create your own extension method or similar, or just rewrite the whole expression to a series of calls and if-statements.

Comment: If each Where method is expected and guaranteed to return 0 or 1 elements, you could use `FirstOrDefault` instead, and assuming `a` is a class, that would give you what you want, but if each step can give more than 1 item, that's not doable with the `??` syntax alone.

Comment: Do you mean "empty" instead of "null"? As it is, the question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own extension method called `NullIfEmpty` like following

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> NullIfEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq)
    {
        if (!seq.Any())
            return null;

        return seq;
    }
}
```

And then you can use this method somewhat like this:

```
return a.Where(...).NullIfEmpty()
        ?? a.Where(...).NullIfEmpty()
        ?? a.Where(...);
```